# Sum multiple columns using PIG

Tags: hadoop, sum, apache-pig

I have multiple files with same columns and I am trying to aggregate the values in two columns using SUM.

The column structure is below

```
ID first_count second_count name desc
1  10          10           A    A_Desc
1  25          45           A    A_Desc
1  30          25           A    A_Desc
2  20          20           B    B_Desc
2  40          10           B    B_Desc
```

How can I sum the first_count and second_count?

```
ID first_count second_count name desc
1  65          80           A    A_Desc
2  60          30           B    B_Desc
```

Below is the script I wrote but when I execute it I get an error "Could not infer matching function for SUM as multiple of none of them fit.Please use an explicit cast.

```
A = LOAD '/output/*/part*' AS (id:chararray,first_count:chararray,second_count:chararray,name:chararray,desc:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY id;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as id,
              SUM(A.first_count) as first_count,
              SUM(A.second_count) as second_count,
              A.name as name,
              A.desc as desc;
```

Comment: Try not using A.* IIRC that is not necessary.  

`SUM(first_count) as first_count,
              SUM(second_count) as second_count,
              name as name,
              desc as desc;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your load statement is wrong. first_count, second_count is loaded as chararray. Sum can't add two strings. If you are sure that these columns will take numbers only then load them as int. Try this-

```
A = LOAD '/output/*/part*' AS (id:chararray,first_count:int,second_count:int,name:chararray,desc:chararray);
```

It should work.